# rawQuery not working in SQLite android

Tags: android, sqlite

All i want to do is set a string equal to one of the entries in my database.  The table i am accessing has 1 column (besides the ID column).  I have been struggling with this for awhile so and even though similar questions have been asked, i am unable to make this situation work.  I am comfortable with some other commands in SQLite but still a beginner.  Here is what i have.  I'm pretty sure once this method works my call from anther class will work fine.

note that both StringCategory_Table and COLUMN_CATEGORIES are defined as Strings.

my database was created with the following (it works fine for everything else except the below method):

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + StringCategory_Table + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_CATEGORIES + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

and here is the method in question (created in a database class using SQLite open helper):

```
public String getCategory(int catId){
Cursor mycursor = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + COLUMN_CATEGORIES  + " FROM "+ StringCategory_Table +" WHERE " + _ID + " = " + catId, null);

//i no longer use this line:String strCatName = mycursor.toString();


String strCatName = mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CATEGORIES));

        return strCatName;
    }
```

**here is my logcat for the above code:**

```
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity  ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.namespace/com.mypackage.namespace.MyCurrentRestaurants}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-04 20:05:47.764: E/AndroidRuntime(9232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
```

**Rather than Delete this question, I will explain what the problems were (as it will be annoying to dig through the comments):**

1. I can't just assign a Class String to a SQLite entry as i was doing.  Instead, i have to open the database before i can read from it: Since i need to open the database before i can read from it, it follows that i need to create an instance of the SQLite database class.
2. Since i am using a cursor, i need to use the moveToFirst method before anything will work.

Thanks to everyone who has helped me today, and please let me know if these conclusions are incorrect as i don't want to spread misconceptions to people as confused as i am.
Adam

Comment: Is there any specific reason to convert the cursor object to a string?
The commented line must have worked.

Comment: i use a string variable to inflate into some views i have already built.  I have think i have to change alot of the code i already made if i dont do it this way.  Is it impossible to convert this object to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public String getCategory(int catId){
        Cursor mycursor = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + COLUMN_CATEGORIES  + " FROM "+ StringCategory_Table +" WHERE " + _ID + " = " + catId, null);
      if(mycursor.moveToFirst()){ //Edited based on suggestion from SAM
          String strCatName = mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CATEGORIES));
                  return strCatName;
        } else {
        return null;
         }


        }
```

Comment: `rawQuery()` will always return a Cursor, so `mycursor` won't be `null`. However `mycursor` might be _empty_, you should check for this with `moveToFirst()`, `moveToNext()`, `getCount()`, etc. before trying to access any "get" method from the Cursor.

Comment: this still dindt work. i noticed a null pointer exception (im pretty new to debugging). any advice on how i might find exactly what is going on?  The database was created perfectly, its just this method that wont work

Comment: after adding some breakpoints, i get "Source not found." if i break right after this line this line of code: 

Cursor mycursor = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + COLUMN_CATEGORIES  + " FROM "+ StringCategory_Table +" WHERE " + _ID + " = " + catId, null);

Comment: FYI: There is probably more to your logcat: a "Caused by ..." line and then a line that begins with " at ...(MyCurrentRestaurants.java:xxx)". The number where I have `xxx` is the last line that executed (the line where the error occurred). You can go straight to this line with Ctrl+L in Eclipse.

Comment: But from what you said `myDatabase` must be `null`. Where did you initialize this? It appears that you never call `myDatabase = ...`.

Comment: Everyone, I would like to apologize for wasting your time with this question.  Sam, your last comment made me do some thinking.  It made me realize that i cant just assign a String to a sqlite entry with a class variable (as i was doing).  Instead, i have to open the database before i can read from it:

entry.openAndWriteToDatabase();
category1 = entry.getCategory(1);
entry.closeTheDatabase();

this was in a different class and i thought that the method was the problem instead of the way i was using it.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that the mycursor.moveToFirst() if statement was definitely necessary.  I thought that the  following line created an object that selected the CATEGORIES_COLUMN entry based on the _ID, so why did i need a moveToFirst() method?????????????

Cursor mycursor = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + COLUMN_CATEGORIES  + " FROM "+ StringCategory_Table +" WHERE " + _ID + " = " + catId, null);

Comment: Yes almost all the time when you working with cursor and trying to get values from it. You need to call cursor.moveToFirst().

Comment: why would i "move to first" if i am trying to read say the 50th entry?  I see no where in the moveToFirst method that uses the desired row as a parameter. thoughts?  (i understand how stupid i sound asking this, but i feel that i need to know if ever want to be good at this)

Comment: @adamkim The Cursor might return the 50th entry but the _Cursor's index_ starts at `-1` and the 50th entry is stored at _index 0_. So we call `moveToNext()` to move the Cursor's index not the row id itself. (I didn't realize we were commenting on VendettaDroid's answer.) Oh well, someone else gets credit for my work...

Comment: So the cursor is almost like an array of its own that stores values based on the query?  If its any consolation, I did up-vote your answers; thought u wanted vendetta to take credit since we were conversing over his answer... looks like he needs the points more than you ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have simply forgot to move the Cursor to the first result. Try this instead:

```
public String getCategory(int catId){
    Cursor mycursor = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + COLUMN_CATEGORIES  + " FROM " + StringCategory_Table +" WHERE " + _ID + " = " + catId, null);

    // Check if the row exists, return it if it does
    if(mycursor.moveToFirst())
        return mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CATEGORIES));

    // No rows match id
    return "";
}
```

Comment: so it still crashes.  any thoughts on why this might happen?  If i dont ever call this method is works fine.  if i call this method even to define any String anywhere in the app it will crash.

Comment: Hmm, cut & paste the logcat errors into your question so I can see what is happening.

Comment: I posted them. after adding some breakpoints, i get "Source not found." if i break right after this line this line of code: 

Cursor mycursor = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + COLUMN_CATEGORIES  + " FROM "+ StringCategory_Table +" WHERE " + _ID + " = " + catId, null);

Answer (score 0):

try working with the sample in the link http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html

instead of converting the cursor object to a string try getting the fields and store it in a string

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your select statement is probably wrong. You should pass the column name string instead of "COLUMN_CATEGORIES" which looks like an integer. After that you should use the commented out way of accessing the string.

Comment: I have COLUMN_CATEGORIES defined as a String earlier in the class; sorry for not putting that in the question (ill do that now). Thanks for the info about the commented out line.