# Cursor value always null android

Tags: android, sqlite

Query executed successfully but curosr given always null value in android studio 1.2.1.1.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * from " + StaticData.SCHOOL_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + "(School_Name LIKE \"%" + Locality1 + "%\") AND"
                + " (City LIKE \"%" + City + "%\" OR Zone LIKE \"%" + City + "%\" ) AND"
                + " State LIKE \"%" + State + "%\" AND"
                + " Country LIKE \"%" + Country + "%\"";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29. Sure its null

Comment: Can you output your String value before the Query is executed? It's hard to say by the code you provided, but perhaps some of your variables aren't properly initialized

Comment: I guess this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269974/rawquery-not-working-in-sqlite-android

Comment: @Raghunandan why sure? what does in the javadoc make you say: sure its null?

Comment: @pskink bcoz op says query gets executed successfully. I just posted the link to the docs.

Comment: @Raghunandan why you say: "sure its null"? what in the docs you linked to, say that the returned `Cursor` will be null?

Comment: @pskink i just posted the link so that op can go through it. Its not say why it will be null. Since the query works fine i was not sure why cursor would be null

Comment: And how do you try to access the cursor after the query?

Comment: Show example values for all these variables, and a database row you think should match.